# Failure to install pyaudio

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

I am attempting to make my own alexa and everytime I try to install pyaudio via the PyCharm terminal it comes up with this huge error:

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\rajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Lo
cal\\Temp\\pip-install-88sq5u2t\\pyaudio_23e33d64381a4b7aa4337aa861032198\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88sq5u2t\\pyaudio_2
3e33d64381a4b7aa4337aa861032198\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import s
etup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-wheel-hc4a9xm0'
       cwd: C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88sq5u2t\pyaudio_23e33d64381a4b7aa4337aa861032198\
  Complete output (9 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\rajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\
Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88sq5u2t\\pyaudio_23e33d64381a4b7aa4337aa861032198\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88sq5u2t\\pyaudio
_23e33d64381a4b7aa4337aa861032198\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
 setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rajan\AppData\L
ocal\Temp\pip-record-n4u5ra3r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\rajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\include\site\py
thon3.9\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88sq5u2t\pyaudio_23e33d64381a4b7aa4337aa861032198\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\rajan\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
 '"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88sq5u2t\\pyaudio_23e33d64381a4b7aa4337aa861032198\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rajan\\AppData\\Local\\Te
mp\\pip-install-88sq5u2t\\pyaudio_23e33d64381a4b7aa4337aa861032198\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.Str
ingIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install -
-record 'C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-n4u5ra3r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\rajan\PycharmProje
cts\jarvisv2\venv\include\site\python3.9\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\jarvisv2\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater.

Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Just download and install those build tools, then try again.

When installing certain packages, certain MS tools are required to build them.

Comment: I did that, installed Visual Studio Installer and installed MS Development for C++, and it did not work. I believe it said 'Failed building wheel for pyaudio'